# Best way to implement "check if app comes from background" in android

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

I have been reading the answers in other post about this topic, but i have not found what is the best of all the approaches.

This is my approach i have now, but i do not know if it worst all the time (as far as i tested every worked for my) or if there is a better way.

```
public class FatherClass extends Activity {

private static int activities = 0;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, String clase) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

protected void onRestart()
{
    super.onRestart();
    if(activities == 0){
        Log.i("APP","BACK FROM BACKGROUND");
    }
}

protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    activities = activities - 1;
}

protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    activities = activities + 1;
}

}
```

Explanation: the **onStart** is executed one the activity is "visible" and the **onStop** when the activity is "not visible". So when your APP (it says APP not activity) goes to background all the activities are "not visible" so they execute the onStop method, so the idea behind this is to **add one** each time an activity es started, and **subtract one** each time an activity es hided, so if the value of the variable "activities" is **0 "zero"** that means that all the activities that where started in some point are now not visible, so when you APP returns from background and executes the **onRestart** method on the activity in "front" you can check whether comes from background or is just restarting an activity.

I would appreciate some feedback regarding this topic.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do *when* your application "comes from background"?

Comment: i want to execute a method, but just when returning from background (the whole app, not the activity)